# Who can help, TradingView Widget Background problems, change the colors

Tags: constructor, widget, overriding, background-color, tradingview-api

Everything does not work as described in the TradingView configurator. I can't manage to adjust the color of the widget. It doesn't even work to change the color of the toolbar. Everything exactly according to TV's [instructions](https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/customization/overrides/chart-overrides#chart-styles) and [documentations](https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/core_concepts/Widget-Constructor/) an still no success. Why is that? Can anyone help?

```
new TradingView.widget({
                "autosize": false,
                "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
                "interval": "1H",
                "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
                "style": "1", // work
                "locale": "en",
                "container_id": "tradingview_chgn",
                "width": "818px",
                "height": "518px",
                "save_image": true,
                "hide_side_toolbar": false,
                "hide_top_toolbar": false,
                "disabled_features": ["create_volume_indicator_by_default"],
                "user_id": 'public_user_id',
                "withdateranges": true,
                "toolbar_bg": "#000000", // does not work
                "theme": "dark",
                "overrides": {
                    "paneProperties.background": "#000000", // does not work
                    "paneProperties.backgroundType": "solid", // does not work
                    "paneProperties.vertGridProperties.color": "#000000", // does not work
                    "paneProperties.horzGridProperties.color": "#000000", // does not work
                    "paneProperties.horzGridProperties.style": "1", // does not work
                    "paneProperties.separatorColor": "#9598a1" // does not work
                }
            });
```

The `WidgetConstructor` from TV is trash if nothing works as specified. Everything was done exactly according to the instructions, but no chance to change the color of the background or anything else.